# Where should I ask for opinions regarding different potential solutions to a programming problem?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm about to implement a complex feature with a bunch of things that can go wrong. Is there a Stack Exchange site where I can describe my problem and a couple of my ideas to solving it?

Comment: Have a look at the [programmers.se](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if what you want fit their on-topic-ness. I assume if your ideas are on architecture or design patterns to be used you should be good to go.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the actual question?

Comment: @AlienArrays No, Code Review is for working code. Not if you're just "about to implement" something.

Comment: "Brainstorming" questions are, as far as I know, off-topic on the while network. Now if you'd have a specific question to specific piece of code, it would be on-topic on SO. If you would have a specific question to specific design, it would be on-topic on Programmers (I think, to be honest I don't know the scope of it very well, check in with their Meta and Help Center to be sure). If you would have some code you would like to be reviewed, that would be CR.

Comment: Thanks for the input.. Guess I can split it up into separate more specific questions relevant for Stackoverflow. Shame there aren't a Stackexchange site for these things.